# Read data from InputStream using Threads

Tags: java, stream, telnet

I tried to use read() method from InputStream class but it blocks the thread, and i tried readLine() method that blocks the thread too.

After this attempts I used this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Socket s = new Socket();
        String host = "";
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 23));

        Response response = new Response(s);

        response .start();

        if(response .isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println(response .getSb().toString());
        }


    }

public class Response extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader s_in = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    public Response(Socket s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            in = s.getInputStream();

            char ch;
            int i;


            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                i = s_in.read();
                ch = (char) i;
                System.out.print(ch);
                getSb().append(getSb());
            }

            System.out.print(getSb());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Response.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public StringBuffer getSb() {
        return sb;
    }
}

public class Message extends Thread{
    Socket s;
    PrintWriter s_out = null;

    public Message(Socket s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            s_out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Message.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the application the socket does not have enough time to send all the data to InputStream.

So, I might verify when the stream ends. To start reading.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you aren't using a buffered stream, or putting this reader in it's own thread, since it should always be reading (or ready to read) from the socket, which means blocking.

But, with the code you've provided, the easiest way to improve your situation is to read until there's no more bytes to read, which is not what you're actually doing.  More bytes could have come in while you're executing the `for` loop.  Try this instead:

```
int i;
char c;
while (in.available() > 0)
{
    i = s_in.read();
    System.out.print(ch = (char)i);
    sb.append(ch);
}
```

It really doesn't solve your problem, because you're not buffering your input with a separate thread, and you can still exit the loop before you receive all the data you expected to get.

Comment: Sorry MBraedley, the variable "s_in" is a BufferedReader. I forgot to put this in the question. And thanks for helping me. I will try this solution.

Comment: MBraedley this solution didnt work. Nothing is printed, means that i didnt receive all the data. Can you explain how i can create to threads. One for read all the data from InpuStream and other to send data using PrintWriter.

Comment: [This is a brief overview of threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). If you are not familiar with threads yet, there may be another solution to look at. Does this app have a main loop? If so, you should be doing a non-blocking read (basically what I provided) at the beginning of the loop, doing everything else you need to do in the loop, and then starting over again. If it's a single fire app, then you need to figure out a way of knowing if you've read everything you need to read, and that determines when you break out of your read loop.

Comment: MBraedley I've just edited the question to be more clear. Running the app like this, I mean in the main method i am still getting any data from inputStream. And yes, i am not familiar with threads, so i dont know how can i use them to read the data.

Comment: Yeah, you're never going to capture everything that way.  You need something to tell the read loop to exit, basically to read forever unless it receives a specific signal, which could be a special character or string to come over the connection.

Comment: MBraedley i've just tried to use Thread to read the data and it goes very well. I will put the solution. But now I want to know how I start both threads "Message" and "Response". And first I read with response, and after i want to stop response, and start message to send some command.